# Tangent bundle of the quotient of matrix Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $G:=GL^+(n)$ (all invertible $n \times n$-matrices with positive determinant) and $K:=SO(n)$. Let $\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{k}$ denote their Lie algebras and $E:=\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$. I would like to understand

> Why the (total space of) tangent space $T(G/K)$ of $G/K$ can be identified with $(G \times E)/K$.

Some facts which are familiar for me:
0. $K$ acts on $E$ via adjoint representation and on $G$ via group multiplication. Thus one has a diagonal action of $K$ on $G \times E$ i.e. $a \cdot (g,x):=(ag,ad(a)x)$. I guess that $(G \times E)/K$ should be understood using this action.
1. if $G$ acts in such a way that $M/G$ is a manifold then we have a *canonical* identification for $x \in M$:
$$T_xM/T_x(G \cdot x) \cong T_{\pi(x)}(M/G)$$ where $G \cdot x$ is the orbit of $x$ and $\pi$ is the canonical projection.
In our case we have for $g \in G$:
$$T_gG/T_g(K \cdot g) \cong T_{\pi(g)}(G/K).$$

Since this correspondence is canonical it should give rise to vector *bundles* isomorphism (but which bundles?).
2. Lie groups are parallelisable thus $TG \cong G \times \mathfrak{g}, TK \cong K \times \mathfrak{k}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: Define $\Phi\colon G\times E \to T(G/H)$ by $\Phi(g,v) = \big(\pi(g),\pi_*(L_{g*}v)\big)$. Check that this induces a well-defined isomorphism on the quotient.

EDIT: In fact, to get well-definedness, it's important to get the action exactly right. Note that $K$ should act on $G$ on the *right* (so that you get a well-defined coset), and so I believe the correct action should be $a\cdot(g,x) = (ga,\text{ad}(a^{-1})x)$. Then note that $$\Phi(ga,\text{ad}(a^{-1})v) = \big(\pi(ga),\pi_*(L_{(ga)*}\text{ad}(a^{-1})v)\big) = \big(\pi(g),\pi_*(L_{g*}L_{a*}L_{a^{-1}*}R_{a*}v)\big) = \big(\pi(g),\pi_*(L_{g*}v)\big),$$
as desired.

Comment: Shouldn't be $(G \times E)/K$ instead of $G \times E$?

Comment: Sorry, my language was sloppy. Edited.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: however I still need some details: first of all, is the quotient $(G \times E)/K$ understood as in my post above? Assume that indeed. We have the map $\pi_K:G \times E \to (G \times E)/K$ where classes in $(G \times E)/K$ are with respect to relation $(g,v) \sim (ag,ava^{-1})$ for some $a \in K$. We would like to define our desired map $(G \times E)?K \to T(G/K)$ by the formula $\pi_K(g,v) \mapsto \Phi(g,v)$. I don't see why this map is well defined: it boils down to showing that $\Phi(g,v)$ and $\Phi(ag,ava^{-1})$ coincide (here$a \in K$): we have $\pi(ag)=\pi(g)$

Comment: but why $\pi_* (L_{ag})_*(ava^{-1})$ and $\pi_*(L_g)_*v$ are the same? Now I will argue as follows: the map $\pi$ is surjective submersion therefore $\Phi$ is surjective. Thus our map $\pi_K(g,v) \mapsto \varphi(g,v)$ is surjective as well. This is (provided we know already that it is well defined!) bundle morhpism: to be bundle isomorphism it suffices to show that it is isomorphism on fibers. But it is surjective on fibers and the (finite) dimensions of fibers coincide thus it is an iso.

Comment: I would like also to understand whether this isomorphism preserves the actions: $G$ acts on $G/K$ via $g_0 \cdot gK:=g_0gK$ (note that $G/K$ is no longer a Lie group-it is only homogenous space). Denote by $L_g:G /K \to G/K$ the corresponding map. Therefore we have an action of $G$ on $T(G/K)$ via $(L_g)_*$. Do we have an action of $G$ on $(G \times E)/K$? The problem that I have is that I don't see the obvious action of $G$ on $E$ ($K$ certainly acts on $E$ but $G$ is larger). Sorry for so many questions but I try to be careful here

Comment: I think you're missing some subtleties in terms of the original action, so I've edited. Your original action won't work.

Comment: With regard to your last question, that's a good point. This is usually done by having an ad-invariant splitting $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak k\oplus \mathfrak m$, with the (reductive) assumption that $[\mathfrak k,\mathfrak m]\subset\mathfrak m$. (So everything's built out of $\mathfrak m$ instead of $E$. Does that help?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64573/discussion-between-truebaran-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: Many thanks for the extending and editing the answer: the problem of well defideness may be considered as solved. According to your remarks about the equivariance of this isomorphism I still lack some details: so if it would be possible, I will be happy to see how the action of $G$ on $(G \times E)/K$ is defined. Obviously one can define this action to make our isomorphism $(G \times E)/K \cong T(G/K)$ equivariant however I doubt whether this is done in such a way.